# Adding an inset map to Arcgis Online web app or web map?

Tags: arcgis-online

Is it possible to add an inset map frame to an ArcGIS Web app? I would ideally have the mid-east as a main focus, then a small inset map of the united states in the corner.

I know how to do this in a static map using ArcMap desktop, but didn't know if it was possible to do in ArcGIS online.

Comment: ArcGIS Online, or a webmap (e.g. written in JavaScript)?

Comment: Either would work really. Although, I would prefer ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 1):

Depends which template you choose.  Many of them include the option to include an overview map.

[Web AppBuilder has an Overview Widget:](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-overview-map.htm)

[image]

The Basic Viewer also has one:

[image]

The [Map Journal](http://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/app-list/map-journal/) is another popular choice, and you can include overview maps here as well:

[image]

Many of the other embedded templates also include the option, but if your developing in the Esri Javascript API, there is a ready to use [Overview widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_overviewmap.html) to make your life easier.

Comment: This is the most straight-forward solution. Another thing you can do is to develop a custom webmap with ArcGIS Javascript Api.

Comment: Those work well @Simon, however I am unable to alter the scale or location that the inset map is displaying. The goal here would be to show information that is off to the side.

Comment: A static inset map?

Comment: Static or dynamic would work.

Comment: Can you be more specific.  You dont want the location to match the same as what is being shown in the map, but want to show somewhere offset to the side?  To override the scale factor % and offset the dynamic overview map will likely involve downloading the template and adjusting the code.  Static is easy.  Create an overview map in ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro, export to JPG, upload somewhere, embed image into sidebar.